# Start TypeScript Echo server DEBUGGING

Tags: java, typescript, debugging, server, webstorm

I need to start a TypeScript echo server over WebStorm and debug it, but I don't know how to do it.

"Bring the template" Echo server" to run. Debug the application
server side (with WebStorm). "

What are the differences when accessing the parameters of a GET or a POST request?

https://mega.nz/#F!f3Z0HSAS!PxjiZeIq3WzZu55re_VM_A

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

- install dependencies by running `npm i` in `server` folder
- open the project in WebStorm via **File | Open**
- in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**, enable **Recompile on changes** to compile your .ts code
- open `server/src/echoserver.ts` in editor to get it compiled
- select the generated `server/src/echoserver.js` in **Project** tree, choose **Run** from its right-click menu => your server will start. To debug, add breakpoints to `server/src/echoserver.ts` and choose **Debug**